# Is it good to use oracle flash back query to get delta records?

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to use Oracle flash back queries to get the delta records from the source systems using Sqoop commands.

Could someone suggest is it good approach to get the delta (insert, update, delete) ?

We followed this to enable FQ: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS1008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. Flashback Query will allow you to tracking history changes for a period, which depends of a lot of factors ( undo retention, level of loading, undo size ). Botton line  you will never be 100% sure that you got what you want.

If you want to be sure that you can retrieve this tracking history changes, for a determined period of time, you must configure Flashback Data Archive.

Regards

Comment: Could you be more specific what does mean 100% not sure ? If we enable Flashback Data Archive do you think I can track and export Insert,Update,Delete records out of oracle DB ? and continue to get the latest changes on every export job run (once 5 hours)

Comment: it means that if you reach for some changes in the past, you cannot be sure 100% to get all those changes because with normal Flashback the changes will be gone once the extensions have been removed from the undo tablespace. If you enable Flashback data  archive, what you are telling Oracle is that you want all the changes produced in a table stored independently of what undo policies you have. Thereby, with FDA, you can get all tracking history changes for a retention period that you can established according to your needs.

Comment: If you want to, I can provide you a test case scenario. Botton line, flashback query is good for cases when you need to track recent changes and you know they are going to be in the undo tablespace, normally because there is enough undo space, enough undo retention and the changes are very recent. Flashback Data Archive assures you that those changes will be there no matter what .

Comment: May you be so kind to accept the answer if you consider so ? I am starting here and I would like to gain some points that I can unlock some options that are not available to me. Thank you